# haproxy serving wrong SSL certificate for a subdomain

Tags: ssl, certificates, haproxy

I have a Server that runs haproxy to redirect incoming traffic to the correct process based on the subdomain. haproxy is configured to use different SSL certificates depending on the subdomain.

The configuration works, however sometimes (quite often though), haproxy serves the wrong certificate (it serves the certificate of another subdomain). I have to refresh the page multiple times in order to get the correct one.

Here is my haproxy configuration:
[haproxy.conf](http://pastebin.com/WZhd2e52)